# Renaming or dealing with pictures copied from other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes("1").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("1").IncrementLeft 100
```

The code copy and paste an image called "1" from sheet2 to sheet1 and then move it. The problem is, I want to copy the same image multiple times and do different things to them (for example, one moves right while another moves down).

However, all the pictures copied share the same name (its original name "1"), and only the first picture pasted responds to the command like "IncrementLeft". In fact, if I manually remove the first picture copied, the second one will start to respond, so it doesn't feel like the later pictures are respected to have different names.

I am wondering if there are any ways to rename or select the picture when I paste them, I don't care about the name of pictures after I paste them. Or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about the name of the pictures after you paste them, you can disregard using the name altogether. Lets assume the pictures pasted to sheet 1 are the only pictures on the sheet at that moment. You can then refer to them without the quotes as so:

```
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes("1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(1).IncrementLeft 100
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(2).IncrementLeft 200
```

Every time you paste another picture, increase the `Shapes(x)` by one, and the newly pasted shape will be targeted, as you now target them by their shape number rather than name.

FYI, you can also change the name if you need to like so:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(2).Name = "3"
```

Also as Chronocidal brilliantly pointed out in the comments, using `Shapes(Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.count)` will count the shapes on that worksheet, and then refer to the last one. So it will always be the one you just added. This is very useful if you have multiple shapes already there, or can't (be bothered to) keep count.

Comment: DIdn't realize I can use index on shapes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, `Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Count)` *should* always be the shape you just pasted...

Comment: @Chronocidal That is very useful indeed, I should have added that to begin with. I have added it to my answer with credit where it is due.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a bit of copying and pasting you could assign the objects to variables and then handle their names. Easier to manage and find them in the future.

```
Sub CopyShape()
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Dim xShape As Shape
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet, copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim originalShape As String, newShape As String

    Set wkbk = ThisWorkbook
    originalShape = "1" 'set original shape name
    newShape = "2" 'set new shape name
    Set copySheet = wkbk.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' set sheet to copy from
    Set pasteSheet = wkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set sheet to paste in

    copySheet.Shapes(originalShape).Copy
    pasteSheet.Activate
    pasteSheet.Paste Range("A1")
    'cycle through each shape in new sheet and check name
    For Each x In pasteSheet.Shapes
        Set xShape = x
        If xShape.Name = originalShape Then Exit For
    Next x
    xShape.Name = newShape

    pasteSheet.Shapes(newShape).IncrementLeft 100
End Sub
```